# Interpolation of product spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, interpolation, interpolation-spaces

Suppose that $X_{\theta}$ is an interpolation space between the Banach spaces $X_0$ and $X_1$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be another Banach space.

**Is it true that $X_{\theta}\times\mathcal{B}$ is an interpolation space between $X_{0}\times\mathcal{B}$ and $X_{1}\times\mathcal{B}$?**

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, interpolation on product spaces works componentwise, so $$\Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i,\prod_{i=1}^n Y_i\Bigr) = \prod_{i=1}^n (X_i,Y_i)$$ for any interpolation functor $(\cdot,\cdot)$ even with equal norms for a fixed choice of $\ell_p$ norm on the product spaces. This follows from the restriction/corestriction theorem in Section 1.2.4 in the <strike>bible</strike> book of Triebel (or alternatively from interpolation for complemented subspaces in Section 1.17.1): One shows that the $j$-th component of the interpolation space of products is exactly $(X_j,Y_j)$.

For this, let $R_j$ be the mapping which extracts the $j$-th component of an $n$-tuple, and let $E_j$ insert the $j$-th component in an $n$-vector of zeroes. Then $E_jR_j$ is a linear continuous projection and $E_jR_j\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a complemented subspace which is isometrically isomorphic to $X_j$; analogously for $Y_j$. Hence, by the mentioned theorem(s), 
$$E_jR_j\Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i,\prod_{i=1}^n Y_i\Bigr) =(X_j,Y_j)$$
and this again isometrically.

---

*Triebel, Hans*, Interpolation theory. Function spaces. Differential operators, Berlin: Deutscher Verlag des Wissenschaften. 528 p. M 87.50 (1978). [ZBL0387.46033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0387.46033).